# phpMyAdmin - Error: The mysqli extension is missing

Tags: php, mysql, linux, phpmyadmin

So just like title said I have been stuck in the error when acceding localhost/phpmyadmin since I installed php7 (I didn't upgrade from php5) on elementary OS.

Things I tried uncommenting this line `extension=mysqli.so in php.ini` sadly it didn't work.

php -v:

> PHP 7.0.20-2~ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jun 14 2017
>   05:33:01) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group Zend Engine
>   v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.20-2~ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.5.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans

mysql --version:

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.35, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using 
>   EditLine wrapper

Any help would be very much appreciated guys. Also, please if you have full explanation why it is not working with php7 enlighten me I'll be very glad to know.

Comment: Install php7-mysql

Comment: Oh man I'm so stupid I followed a tutorial wrote all commands but skipped that one. Can you please answer this question so I can accept your answer?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww I believe the close reason you are referring to is the following: `off-topic: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.` I would say both PHP and MySQL are tools "used primarily for programming". Nonetheless, I believe this question should be closed since it was solved in a way unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: It is not off topic since those are main tools for programming. But there's no way this can help anyone, I cannot afford stack to maintain a question where I irresponsibly forgot to write a command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the php MySQL driver.

Install php7-mysql by running this:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

Comment: Had to reboot after that.... didn't identify the service to reboot. In my case it was php5.6

Comment: You don't have to reboot, just need to restart service.

Answer (score 3):

Do you even have the extension installed? Try running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

Comment: Thanks man, mkaatman has already put the light on my sloppiness. I had a set of commands line and forgot that one so...

Comment: @OussamaBenGhorbel glad to hear you got it working. I have to admit I have made the same mistake a few times in the past.